# How to have a different row width on css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Ok so I have a grid that has 4 rows and 3 columns, I will like to make the last 3 rows to be like half the size of the full grid and to be in the horizontal center below the 1st row. I have tried multiple ways to do that and none of them have worked like having a nested grid, maybe I did it wrong.

```css
.user-header {
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.user-header .grid-header {
  width: 46%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 15% 30% 30% 45%;
  grid-gap: .2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.grid-header-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-header-item:nth-child(10) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 4;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-header">
  <div class="grid-header">
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey 
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Here is how the grid should be (I did this on paint)]

Comment: Can you add some simple image of desired result?

Comment: @focus.style I will add that image right now, I tryed my best to do it on pait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily you could make all in flex.

Html:

```
<div id=“user-header”>
     <div class=“header-item-long”>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class=“header-item-small”>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class=“header-item-small”>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hey
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class=“header-item-large”>
      <div class=“header-text”>
       Hay
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#user-header {
width: 100%;
height: your size;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

#user-header .header-item-long {
Width:100%;
Height: your size;
Display: flex;
Flex-direction: row;
Justify-content:center;
}

#user-header .header-item-small {
Width: 100%;
Height: your size;
Display: flex;
Flex-direction: row;
Justify-content: center;
Padding: 0 50px;
}

#user-header .header-item-large {
Width: 100;
Height: your size;
Display: flex;
Flex-direction: row;
Align-items: center;
Justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: If missing something let me know :) writing on phone

Comment: make the grid 12 columns with each item in the first row 4 columns each, then the next 3 rows, each item is 2 columns each starting at column 4, etc.

Comment: @MaciejGromadzki The code seems to work except that the first header-item-small on the html is not align to the second one, this is because in my actual code the first header-item-small (represents numbers) and the second one shows (text) It is like IG following follower posts counter.

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala you can try to set up a container inside with width let’s say 200/300 px. That could help

Comment: @ChrisL can you help me with an answer please?

Comment: I did. I’m not going to write your code for you. If you want to actually learn something, there is plenty of information a W3 schools and CSS tricks about CSS grid. Go there and read up and try to write the code for the grid the way I described it and if you still can’t figure it out then post what you tried and I’ll help you fix it.

Comment: @ChrisL Hey Chris! I make it work! thanks for the idea;)

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Grid is not a simple solution here because grid tracks make centering on the row problematic.

Flex may be a better option for you. Here's one concept:

```css
.grid-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 46%;
}

.grid-header-item:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  flex: 1 0 26%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.grid-header-item:nth-child(n + 4) {
  flex: 0 0 24%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.grid-header-item:last-child {
  flex-basis: calc(72% + 10px);
}

.grid-header-item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-header">
  <div class="grid-header">
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>    
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Michael, by some reason, your code is appearing on a single column on my server, can that be something to do with user-header css?

Comment: Not sure why. Maybe update your question with more code.

Answer (score 0):

I think - `flex` solutions from other answerers are pretty nice. Just want to illustrate who is this even possible using `grid`. Not pretending on the best or the most flexible solution, but it is possible using grid too.

More about `grid-template-areas` here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template-areas.asp

```css
.grid-header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 15% 30% 30% 45%;
  grid-template-areas:
    'r1c1 r1c1 r1c1 r1c1 r1c2 r1c2 r1c2 r1c2 r1c3 r1c3 r1c3 r1c3' 
    '. . . r2c1 r2c1 r2c2 r2c2 r2c3 r2c3 . . .'
    '. . . r3c1 r3c1 r3c2 r3c2 r3c3 r3c3 . . .'
    '. . . r4c1 r4c1 r4c1 r4c1 r4c1 r4c1 . . .';
  grid-gap: .2rem;
}

.grid-header-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: cyan;
}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(1) {grid-area: r1c1;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(2) {grid-area: r1c2;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(3) {grid-area: r1c3;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(4) {grid-area: r2c1;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(5) {grid-area: r2c2;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(6) {grid-area: r2c3;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(7) {grid-area: r3c1;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(8) {grid-area: r3c2;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(9) {grid-area: r3c3;}
.grid-header-item:nth-child(10) {grid-area: r4c1;}
```

```html
<div class="user-header">
  <div class="grid-header">
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey 
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey 
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-item">
      Hey
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I followed Cris's idea of having 12 columnsand that the first row ocupies the whole 12 columns while the rest of them occopied 6 columns(from 4th to 9th column)